# type="number" use only CustomValidator

Tags: parsley.js

How to I remove the builtIn "Integer" Validator from a html5 number field, but still use my CustomValidator?

My field:

```
<input id="temp" name="temp"  type="number" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-number_international="" class="form-control">
```

My Custom Code:

```
window.ParsleyValidator
.addValidator('number_international',
  function (value, requirement) {
      if (format == '1'){
          var reg = /^\d+(,\d+)*$/;
      } else {
          var reg = /^\d+(.\d+)*$/;
      }
      var res = reg.test(value);

      return res;
  }, 32)  
.addMessage('en', 'number_international', 'Only numbers allowed!')
.addMessage('de', 'number_international', 'Nur Zahlen und Komma erlaubt!');
```

Thanks

Hannes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went back from "number" field type to "text" field type because I had serveral issues how "number" handles the comma separator. I let the user choose if he wants "," or "." as comma but it looks like I cannot change what Chrome or Firefox automatically expects.

Cheers
Hannes